# How to detect user events with Jetpack Compose UI via Reactive Programming?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, reactive-programming

How can I detect when a `UI` change is triggered by a user click on a `UI` element in the `Jetpack Compose` system like a click in a list of items? Is it possible to use `Reactive Programming` for this like `RxKotlin` or `RxJava` with observables?

Comment: Do u want to detect click event for a composable..?

Comment: @Abhijithmogaveera Yes, that is the objective.

Comment: every composable accepts modifier parameter so u can do this modifier = Modifier.clickable {  }

Comment: @Abhijithmogaveera this is used to DO something when an element is clicked. I want to only DETECT that the element is clicked.

Comment: try with answer that I have just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in reactive way using MutableInteractionSource. You can collect touch, drag or hover events if they are emitted. Modifier.clickable emits press events.

```
@Composable
private fun InteractionFlowExample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {

        val interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()
        val context = LocalContext.current

        LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
            interactionSource.interactions
                .onEach { interaction: Interaction ->

                    if (interaction is PressInteraction.Press) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Pressed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    } else if (interaction is PressInteraction.Release) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Released",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }

                }
                .launchIn(this)
        }

        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(4 / 3f)
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = rememberRipple(),
                    onClick = {}
                ),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text(
                text = "Collect Interactions",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add interactions into a list and remove them as in [official document](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/handling-interaction#working-with-interactionsource).

```
@Composable
private fun CollectStatesExample() {

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val interactions = remember { mutableStateListOf<Interaction>() }

    LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        interactionSource.interactions.collect { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    interactions.add(interaction)
                }
                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    interactions.remove(interaction.press)
                }
                is PressInteraction.Cancel -> {
                    interactions.remove(interaction.press)
                }
                is DragInteraction.Start -> {
                    interactions.add(interaction)
                }
                is DragInteraction.Stop -> {
                    interactions.remove(interaction.start)
                }
                is DragInteraction.Cancel -> {
                    interactions.remove(interaction.start)
                }

            }
        }
    }


    val lastInteraction = when (interactions.lastOrNull()) {
        is DragInteraction.Start -> "Drag Start"
        is DragInteraction.Stop -> "Drag Stop"
        is DragInteraction.Cancel -> "Drag Cancel"
        is PressInteraction.Press -> "Pressed"
        is PressInteraction.Release -> "Press Release"
        is PressInteraction.Cancel -> "Press Cancel"
        else -> "No state"
    }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(2.dp, Blue400)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource, rememberRipple()
            ) {}

            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Text(lastInteraction, modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
modifier = Modifier
                        .pointerInteropFilter {
                            when(it.action ){
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN->{
                                    Log.e("PIII","DOWN")
                                    //user press
                                }
                                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP->{
                                    Log.e("PIII","UP")
                                    //user release
                                }
                                else->{
                                    Log.e("PIII","Other")
                                    //other event
                                }
                            }
                            true
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Modifier.clickable {} to detect clicks on an element

Comment: How would I detect when the user clicks on a list item in a dropdown menu `OutlinedTextField`?