# How to know idle / inactivity time in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've implemented an idle timer (i.e. for auto logout) in regular `View` / `Activity` projects in a variety of ways, now I'm kind of new developing `Compose` based apps, and all the solutions I find looks like old fashioned.

**Any recommended good practice to get idle / inactivity time the Compose way?**

Comment: I guess you would need to listen to the users touch events and than start a counter when he interacts with your screen. Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74792965/how-to-detect-user-events-with-jetpack-compose-ui-via-reactive-programming

Comment: Thank you @basti394, I was wondering if there's something more 'generic', as gestures won't trigger on some interactions such as focusing a textfield or typing in the keyboard. Still, a gesture based approach would probably be good enough, so thank you again :)